Unknown stalker movie from 90s
I'm looking for the title of this stalker movie that I thought was from 90's or early 2000.  The movie is about this lonely woman and this stalker who begins watching her after an interaction in the park.  He watches her constantly with binoculars and even ends up having a brief relationship with her. She then breaks up with him when she realizes he is crazy.   
The scene I remember is that the stalker sneaks into her apartment and rubs all of her bed sheets with poison ivy.  The woman gets a horrible case and isn't able to go to work for a while. I wish I remembered more. I thought it was in indie movie.  At the end of the movie the stalker kills the woman and he gets away. Any help would be great.  Thanks.  

This sounds like the exact plot of the indie thriller Alone With Her.

Alone With Her is the harrowing story of a disturbed young man's attempts to win the affections of an unsuspecting young woman. When Doug (Colin Hanks) first sees Amy (Ana Claudia Talancon), he instantly falls for her and begins to watch her every move, going so far as to set up spy cameras in her apartment. However, as his fascination grows into obsession he's no longer satisfied with just watching.

Everything you described is there: He stalks her in the park, laces her bedsheets with poison ivy leading to a bad rash, and develops a relationship with her. When she realizes he's crazy, he kills her and the film ends with him stalking a new victim (though there's an alternative ending where she lives). The year is a bit off, though (2006). The entire film was shot through spy cameras. Here's the trailer:




@Jim No problem, but don't forget to click on the check mark next to the answer to approve it (from your original account).
